# Integrate Capybara in SInatra app with rspec result always in 504 tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, capybara

I don't get capybara working with my modular sinatra app. I created a small test app and have the same issue. I get always a 504 Timeout Error and i think that the app isn't really loaded by Capybara regardless the Line `Capybara.app = Testapp` in the acceptance_helper.

Browser Firefox opens when test is running but don't go to any URL and shows always a blank site.

When i do the same test only with rspec it works (second one).

What i'm doing wrong?

**My Setup:**

```
OS: Win 7 Professional 64-bit
Ruby version: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
Firefox version: 40.0.3

gem versions
- sinatra (1.4.6)
- rspec (3.3.0)
- capybara (2.7.1)
- selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)
- thin (1.5.1)  
- rack (1.6.4)
- rack-test (0.6.3)
```

**App structure:**

```
test_sinatra_capybara
 |
 |- testapp.rb
 |- spec
 |    |- spec_helper.rb
 |    |- acceptance_helper.rb
 |    |- testapp_spec.rb
 |- views
 |    |- index.slim
```

**testapp.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'slim'

class Testapp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    slim :index
  end
end
```

**index.slim**

```
#test-id
  | Willkommen
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rack/test'
require_relative '../testapp'
Testapp.environment = :test

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app() Testapp end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RSpecMixin
  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

**acceptance_helper.rb**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/spec_helper'

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.app = Testapp

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
end
```

**testapp_spec.rb**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/acceptance_helper'

describe 'URLs that require login' do
  it "start page capybara" do
    # I tried both
    visit '/'
    # visit 'http:localhost:4567'

    page.should have_content("Willkommen")
  end

  it "start page rspec" do
    get "/"

    expect(last_response.body).to include("Willkommen")
  end
end
```

So as i said, last test is working:

```
Finished in 12.91 seconds (files took 2.54 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/testapp_spec.rb:4 # URLs that require login start page capybara
```

Error on First test:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unexpected response, code=504, content-type="text/html"
```

Comment: If you pause the test after the `visit` what url is the browser attempting to connect to?

Comment: Your right with the Proxy matter. I forgot to show that Info. But Localhost (127.0.0.1) should not be affected. And i manually disabled it and still not working.

Window of the Browser is always blank so capybara can open the browser but then it fails to go to any url in my opinion.

My current FF version is 40.0.3, maybe a reason i will try this out as last, because in my opionion it is not to old. Selenium gem is 2.53.4



Thx for the Capybara.server_* config stuff i didn't know that but it is still failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the exact code posted works fine for me, which I'm guessing means one of two things.  Either the version of Firefox you're using is outdated (make sure you're using 47.0.1) or you're on a machine that has a proxy server or firewall that is interfering with requests to 127.0.0.1:<some random port>.  The default Capybara config starts up a server on 127.0.0.1:<random port> to handle requests for the app under test.  If those connections are blocked or proxied elsewhere it will obviously prevent things from working properly.  If you need to bind to a different interface or set a fixed port to get around corporate firewall/proxy restrictions you can do that by setting Capybara.server_host and Capybara.server_port

Comment: It has todo with some very weird stuff in my setup.

I have babun (cygwin) installed and always running tests from that point. When i do it in a plain cmd of Windows its working...why ever but it is a solution for me now.

I will give you right answer anyway because my setup was broken and your answer gives me some new information i can do to setup capybara. THX.